# Games on SSD with Steam

Tags: steam

As I want to save as much space on my main SSD for games, to optimize performance for none Steam games. I would love to have these games on another drive.

**Is it possible to install Steam games on my external SSD, plug and un-plug it for whenever I want to play these Steam games?**

Comment: How do you plan to 'plug and unplug' the SSD? I am pretty sure doing it via USB will kill any ssd performance you would get.

Comment: What @ColinD said - you're not going to get anywhere near the speedup over USB that you would over proper SATA (although eSATA would be fine).

Comment: USB would kill sequential speeds, but you would still have the big advantage of random IO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Steam games on an external drive. When installing a game, it asks where you want to install. By default, this will point at your SteamApps. You can use the dropdown menu to select your external SSD and create a new Steam library folder and install the game there.

You may need to restart Steam after plugging in the drive.

If you don't see the dropdown, make sure your Steam is up-to-date.

*(Sorry for non-English screen capture)*

[image: Steam Install]

Comment: Mhh....sounds reasonable. I would test is with a small game, before trying it on a big one. But steam is quite good with recognising games...

Comment: This is the preferred method of installing games on another drive, however it will only work with games that use the SteamPipe content system. Luckily, most games these days use it.